# How to force Apollo Client to use cached data for detail view page

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a paginated cursor based query **TODOS** and detail page with query **TODO** to get data by ID.
Whenever I go to detail view and use **useQuery** with **TODO** query (Which contains exactly same data as **TODOS** query result, it still tries to get data from server not from cache. How can I achieve to not get data from server (Because it already exists), I thought Apollo detect by id and return from the cache but no. Any suggestions ?

Similar issue as no this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45922127/how-to-force-apollo-client-to-use-cached-data), but I don't think thats a right approach, there should be better solution. (I hope)

This is **TODOS** query:

```
query TODOS(
  $paginationOptions: PaginationOptionsInput
) {
  todos(paginationOptions: $paginationOptions) {
    pagination {
      minCursor
      maxCursor
      sortOrder
      limit
      hasMoreResults
    }
    result {
     id
     ...SomeTodoFields
  }
}
```

And on detail page I have second query **TODO**

```
query (
  $todoId: String!
) {
  todo(todoId: $todoId) {
    id
    ...SomeTodoFields
  } 
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code so that we can give you some direction? ApolloClient is meant to look in the cache before making any queries, unless you explicitly tell it to not use the cache - you may be doing something unexpected which is causing the cache to be overlooked.

Comment: Will Update in a min.

Comment: If the fields under paginated TODOS query and single TODO query are the same and shouldn't it return from the cache or it needs some extra configuration to achieve that?

Comment: So the main thing you need to be checking is the __typename returned from your TODO query result, and the results section of your TODOS query. The idea is that if the __typenames match for those objects, then ApolloClient is able to determine that they are the same and thus perform the correct cache query. My suggestion would be to add the __typename field to each of those queries and compare the results as a first step.

Comment: __typename is a little bit different, since TODOS query is paginated one, it returns paginatedTodosType as a root __typename and it has result field - array of __typeName: todoType. When I am fetching TODO query I am getting single object of __typeName: todoType

Comment: So the fact that they both share the __typeName of todoType should be enough for that equality check to figure out they are the same objects and use the cached value. You can now try to use a fetchPolicy of "cache-only", it will only use the cache to retrieve the data - if it cannot find it, it will throw an error. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#configuring-fetch-logic

Comment: Yes I already tried "cache-only" policy and data was undefined. Since you are saying that it should be working, I will check everything one more time to make sure that fields are the same and not requesting some new one which cause this server request. Thank you for help!

Comment: @Phobos I checked and fields are the same but it still sends request to the server. Lets say I fetched 10 items and I opened first one ( as a detail page), then wen back and open first one again - only then it takes data from the cache, so, since TODO query doesn't exists yet it tries to fetch from the server, but couldn't figure out how to connect TODOS and single TODO query to each other, to prevent server request from TODO query.

Comment: Couldn't solve yet but, found the spot where to dig (If someone wonders) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52927310/when-to-use-apollos-cacheredirects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I am using Apollo-client < 3.0 for me cacheRedirect worked fine, you can have a look farther [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/advanced-topics/#cache-redirects-using-field-policy-read-functions). Read every note carefully it is really important! My code example:

```
cache: new InMemoryCache({
    fragmentMatcher,
    cacheRedirects: {
      Query: {
        todo: (_, args, { getCacheKey }) => {
          return getCacheKey({ __typename: 'TodoType', id: args.todoId })
        }
      }
    }

  })
})
```

Found some good relevant [article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/basics-of-caching-data-in-graphql-7ce9489dac15) as well, which you might want to check.
This worked for me, hope it helps to someone else as well. :)